# Best gradient free methos to converge a 2 layers Neural Network on MNIST?

Tags: neural-network

We've developed a C++ Neural Network that work on the MNIST dataset.
We don't want to use back-propagation.
Are there optimal methods to avoid it and have the net to converge to high accuracies?

Comment: We wrote an initial implementation of Particle Swarm Optimization for a 2 layers NN in https://github.com/fportera/PSO_Neural_Nets

Comment: We think some works have been carried on this topic: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.04089.pdf and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.01526.pdf, at least.